# PHP simpleXML get value of different nodes depending on value

Tags: php, xml, simplexml

I have the following XML code:

```
<administration>
    <notes>
        <note>
            <id>12312312</id>
            <name>Lorem Ipsum</name>
            <reference>Target Value - 1</reference>
        </note>
        <note>
            <id>12312365</id>
            <name>Lorem Ipsum</name>
            <references>
                <code>Dolor it se met.</code>
                <code>Target Value - 2</code>
            </references>
        </note>
        <note>
            <id>12375512</id>
            <name>Target Value - 3</name>
            <reference>S</reference>
        </note>
    </notes>
    <accounting>
        <ledgers>
            <ledger>
                <debits>
                    <debit>
                        <description>Target Value - 4</description>
                        <amount>5467.32</amount>
                    </debit>
                    <debit>
                        <description>My Debit</description>
                        <amount>5467.32</amount>
                        <tags>
                            <tag>Target Value - 5</tag>
                        </tags>
                    </debit>
                </debits>
                <credits>
                    <credit>
                        <title>Target Value - 6</title>
                        <amount>873.00</amount>
                    </credit>
                    <credit>
                        <description>Target Value - 7</description>
                        <amount>23454.12</amount>
                    </credit>
                </credits>
            </ledger>
        </ledgers>
    </accounting>
</administration>
```

I'm trying to get a PHP array which consists of only the values of the nodes which have a value containing this string: "Target Value".
This has to be done on a recursive way, using an XML parser (I'm trying SimpleXML, but I'm new to that).

Up 'till now, I've been trying to use SimpleXmlIterator and foreach- and for-loops to achieve this, but I can't seem to check if a node value contains "Target Value".

Edit: reaching the target nodes by manually referring to them is not what I'm looking for, if I were, there would be no problem

Is there any way to achieve this?

EDIT:

Here is the code of my last try:

```
function sxiToArray($sxi)
{
    $a = array();
    for( $sxi->rewind(); $sxi->valid(); $sxi->next() )
    {
        if(!array_key_exists($sxi->key(), $a))
        {
            $a[$sxi->key()] = array();
        }
        if($sxi->hasChildren())
        {
            if (strpos((string)$sxi->current(), "Target Value"))
                $a[$sxi->key()][] = sxiToArray($sxi->current());
        }
        else
        {
            if (strpos((string)$sxi->current(), "Target Value"))
                $a[$sxi->key()][] = strval($sxi->current());
        }
    }
    return $a;
}

$xmlArray = xml2array('../Document.xml');
print_r($xmlArray);
```

This gives the following result after running:

Array ( [notes] => Array ( ) [accounting] => Array ( ) )

Comment: Can you post the code you tried with the SimpleXmlIterator?

Comment: why not use regex if you dont want to use loops or compare values?

Comment: @khuderm What exactly do you mean by using regex? Should I check every node with the regex comparison material?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It does not have to be done in an recursive way. You can use Xpath. Xpath uses location paths as part of an expression. The paths use different axes - one of them is descendant. It "ignores" the nesting. Xpath allows you to use conditions.

- Get any element node in the document
  `//*`
- That has a text node as an child
  `//*[./text()]`
- with the text node containing the string "Target Value"
  `//*[./text()[contains(., "Target Value")]]`

Put together it is a fairly small piece of code:

```
$administration = new SimpleXMLElement($xml);
$nodes = $administration->xpath('//*[./text()[contains(., "Target Value")]]');

foreach ($nodes as $node) {
  var_dump($node->getName(), (string)$node);
}
```

Output:

```
string(9) "reference"
string(16) "Target Value - 1"
string(4) "code"
string(16) "Target Value - 2"
string(4) "name"
string(16) "Target Value - 3"
string(11) "description"
string(16) "Target Value - 4"
string(3) "tag"
string(16) "Target Value - 5"
string(5) "title"
string(16) "Target Value - 6"
string(11) "description"
string(16) "Target Value - 7"
```

And with DOM it would not look much different:

```
$document = new DOMDocument();
$document->loadXml($xml);
$xpath = new DOMXpath($document);

$nodes = $xpath->evaluate('//*[./text()[contains(., "Target Value")]]');

foreach ($nodes as $node) {
  var_dump($node->localName, $node->textContent);
}
```

Comment: Thank you, this was exactly what I was looking for.

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you try str_pos() for "Target value"? I don't exactly know how you iterate through the XML but you could do something like:

```
if(str_pos($node, "Target value"){
    //do whatever
}
```

That will tell you if any of the nodes at least contain that specific string.

Comment: I have done something like this already, but my assignment specifically noted the use of a recursive way....